# How do I enable all Intel Intrinsic options in GCC?

Tags: gcc, x86, intrinsics

Referencing the GCC built in functions here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html

You can enable these functions by specifying compile flags, example: gcc -mavx main.c

Is there a flag options that enables all of these?

Comment: Note that `-mavx` will not only enable AVX intrinsics, but also enable automatically generated AVX instructions by compiler. So if you enable every possible intrinsic you may end up compiling a binary that won't run on your machine. Perhaps you'd rather want an option to enable all intrinsics that works for your machine? There's `-march=native` for that.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I'm trying to write a benchmark program and will be doing run-time checks to only execute the intrinsics if they're supported on the machine where the executable is running.

Comment: You might want to use per-function attributes like `__attribute__((target("avx")))`.  It's not safe to execute code compiled with `-mavx` on a machine that might not have AVX, because that gives the compiler permission to use AVX instructions *itself*.  Unlike MSVC, GCC's overall design for CPU-feature stuff never allows using intrinsics for instructions the compiler isn't allowed to use itself.  (inline asm still works, but that's very different and usually undesirable.)  The other main option is to put your AVX functions in a file compiled with `-mavx`, and not use that for other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `-march=native` if you want to use all the instrinsic of your local CPU.

- option `-march=cpu-type`

> Generate instructions for the machine type cpu-type. In contrast to
> -mtune=cpu-type, which merely tunes the generated code for the specified cpu-type, -march=cpu-type allows GCC to generate code that
> may not run at all on processors other than the one indicated.
> Specifying -march=cpu-type implies -mtune=cpu-type, except where noted
> otherwise.

- if cpu-type is `native`

> This selects the CPU to generate code for at compilation time by
> determining the processor type of the compiling machine. **Using
> -march=native enables all instruction subsets supported by the local machine** (hence the result might not run on different machines).
> Using -mtune=native produces code optimized for the local machine
> under the constraints of the selected instruction set.

If you are targeting other CPUs, you want to target the smallest subset of intrinsics. But the instrinsic set is not always growing in the following architectures. For instance, not all instructions in `tigerlake` are in `alderlake`, and reciprocally:

> Intel **Tigerlake** CPU with 64-bit extensions, MOVBE, MMX, SSE, SSE2,
> SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, POPCNT, PKU, AVX, AVX2, AES, PCLMUL,
> FSGSBASE, RDRND, FMA, BMI, BMI2, F16C, RDSEED, ADCX, PREFETCHW,
> CLFLUSHOPT, XSAVEC, XSAVES, AVX512F, AVX512VL, AVX512BW, AVX512DQ,
> AVX512CD, AVX512VBMI, AVX512IFMA, SHA, CLWB, UMIP, RDPID, GFNI,
> AVX512VBMI2, AVX512VPOPCNTDQ, AVX512BITALG, AVX512VNNI, VPCLMULQDQ,
> VAES, PCONFIG, WBNOINVD, MOVDIRI, MOVDIR64B, AVX512VP2INTERSECT and
> KEYLOCKER instruction set support.
>
> Intel **Alderlake** CPU with 64-bit extensions, MOVBE, MMX, SSE, SSE2,
> SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, POPCNT, AES, PREFETCHW, PCLMUL, RDRND,
> XSAVE, XSAVEC, XSAVES, XSAVEOPT, FSGSBASE, PTWRITE, RDPID, SGX, UMIP,
> GFNI-SSE, CLWB, MOVDIRI, MOVDIR64B, CLDEMOTE, WAITPKG, ADCX, AVX,
> AVX2, BMI, BMI2, F16C, FMA, LZCNT, PCONFIG, PKU, VAES, VPCLMULQDQ,
> SERIALIZE, HRESET, KL, WIDEKL and AVX-VNNI instruction set support.

Reference:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html